# I want to use map instead of 2 for loops

Tags: apex, map

I have a situation where I have a case object which has the Asset Object as its child. I need to check whether a case has an asset with the name 'Test' and then use the created date field of that Test Asset and display it a component.

The logic is working however, I want to optimize the code so that it doesn't use two for loops and use Maps instead, can someone help me with the code?

Here's a snippet what I have now:

```
if(caseId != null){
    caseList = [SELECT Id, Certificate_Issue_Date__c,(SELECT Id, Name, Status, CreatedDate from Assets__r WHERE Name IN('Test') AND Status='Accepted') FROM Case WHERE Id=:caseId WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED LIMIT 1];
}
if(caseList.size() > 0){
    for(Case caseRec:caseList){
        if(caseRec.Assets__r.size() > 0){
            for(Asset assetRec: caseRec.Assets__r){
                if(assetRec.Name == 'Test'){
                    sentDate= assetRec.CreatedDate;                  
                }
            }
        }                
    }
    //DO some other calculations here
}
```

Comment: why do you need to iterate over asset again   in inner for loop.  you are already  checking in query  asset name in ('Test').   is there any specific reason to check if name is test.  if not  , remove inner for loop for asset  and assign sentDate  with  caseRec.Assets__r[0].createddate

Comment: I had shared a snippet to make the requirement precise, however, to elaborate a bit: I have multiple assets records. I need the value of 'Test" to display a value and I need the value of "Test 2" to display another value. In short I am collecting values from multiple assets and displaying a summarized information. That is why I need the second loop and need to iterate over assets.

Comment: As @sfdcfox has mentioned   nested loops are not necessarily bad.  so your current solution is fine.   if you want to go by map approach it will only complicate things  which need to be weighed upon what improvement  it can bring to performance.   based  on  your problem statement.  you need case id  as map key  but in addition  you also need assetname  as key        so  map  structure can become complicate  something like  Map<id, Map<String,Asset>>   id -> caseid   String - assetname    Asset - asset sobject  .   you have to modify  your soql  query also in 2 parts  to go by map approach

Comment: i would say your current solution is fine for now considering all these points.   but in case  you are facing any performance issue   it would be better  if you share  your complete logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I've [said before](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/282831/2984), nested loops are not necessarily bad. You can't really use a map in this situation without otherwise having loops involved anyways. However, that's all overly complicated; if you just want to know if there's a 'test' record, you can write:

```
try {
  Case record = [SELECT Id, Certificate_Issue_Date__c,(SELECT Id, Name, Status, CreatedDate from Assets__r WHERE Name IN('Test') AND Status='Accepted' LIMIT 1) FROM Case WHERE Id=:caseId WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED LIMIT 1];
  Boolean hasTestAsset = record.Assets__r.size() > 0;
  if(hasTestAsset) {
    sentDate = record.Assets__r[0].CreatedDate;
  }
} catch(Exception e) {
  throw new AuraHandledException('Case could not be accessed.');
}
```

You already had a filter of `Name='Test'` and `Status='Accepted'`, so the other if statement wasn't necessary, nor was a loop.

Note that if the case record isn't found, you'll get an exception anyways, so most of your code isn't necessary. You can just wrap this code in a try-catch block, since presumably you can't continue on without the case record.

---

Edit: Based on your comments, it sounds like you may want a Map after all. That's trivially easy enough:

```
Map<String, Asset__c> assetsByName = new Map<String, Asset__c>();
Case caseRecord = [SELECT ... FROM Case ...];
for(Asset__c assetRecord: caseRecord.Asset__r) {
  assetsByName.put(assetRecord.Name, assetRecord);
}
```

...

```
Asset__c testAssetRecord = assetsByName.get('Test');
if(testAssetRecord != null) {
  // Do something with this record
}
// etc
```

Comment: One of the main points I was going for in my (now scrapped) answer was that this approach (using a subquery) uses a single SOQL query whereas using a Map (to avoid a nested loop) would require a second query. There are few circumstances where I would choose to turn one query into two. If my understanding of how subqueries are handled in Apex is correct, limiting the subquery to a single row should also completely avoid the _"Aggregate query has too many rows for direct assignment"_ error that subqueries can run into.

Comment: I had shared a snippet to make the requirement precise, however, to elaborate a bit: I have multiple assets records. I need the value of 'Test" to display a value and I need the value of "Test 2" to display another value. In short I am collecting values from multiple assets that are of "Accepted" status and displaying a summarized information. That is why I need the second loop and need to iterate over assets.

Comment: I wonder whether exception handling in Apex includes the [performance drawbacks](http://java-performance.info/throwing-an-exception-in-java-is-very-slow/) that (used to?) impact Java? Also given the comment from the OP, above, perhaps an aggregate query might be in order?

Comment: @PhilW Yes, exception handling is prohibitively expensive to use as a "normal" use case, e.g. in a loop. Last I tested, it took 80-100ms to unwind even a trivially small stack. I recommend it here only because the exception is meant to terminate the transaction and send an error back to the user, rather than in a tight loop.

Comment: @InduPrasad Fair enough. I added an edit to help out here. You still don't necessarily need the first loop, though, but having a Map does tend to make it easier to read.