# Hi guys, can you please help me rewrite the nested loop from the end of the codes

Tags: apex, loop

```
//triggers
rigger MaintenanceRequest on Case (after update) {
    MaintenanceRequestHelper.updateWorkOrders(Trigger.New);
}

public with sharing class MaintenanceRequestHelper {
    public static void updateWorkOrders(List <Case> newList) {
        Set <Id> closedCaseIdset = new Set<Id>();
        
        for (Case c : newList){
            if (c.Status == 'Closed' && c.Type == 'Repair' || c.Type == 'Routine Maintenance'){
                    closedCaseIdset.add(c.Id);
            }
        }
        
        Map <ID, Decimal> requestToCycleMap = new Map <ID, Decimal>();
        AggregateResult [] groupedResults = [ Select Maintenance_Request__c, MIN(Equipment__r.Maintenance_Cycle__c) 
                                             cycle From Equipment_Maintenance_Item__c
                                                    Where Maintenance_Request__c IN : closedCaseIdset
                                            Group by Maintenance_Request__c];
        
        for(AggregateResult ar : groupedResults)
        {
            requestToCycleMap.put((Id)ar.get('Maintenance_Request__c'), (Decimal)ar.get('cycle'));
        }
        
        Map <Id,List<Equipment_Maintenance_Item__c>> requestIdToEquipmentsMap = new Map <Id,List<Equipment_Maintenance_Item__c>>();
        List <Case> maintenanceRequestInsert = new List <Case>();
        
        For (Case caseRecord : [Select Id, Vehicle__c,ProductId, (Select Id, Equipment__c, Quantity__c From Equipment_Maintenance_Items__r)
                               From Case Where Id IN : closedCaseIdset])
        {
            requestIdToEquipmentsMap.put(caseRecord.Id, caseRecord.Equipment_Maintenance_Items__r);
            case nc = new case();
            nc.ParentId = caseRecord.Id;
            nc.Vehicle__c = caseRecord.Vehicle__c;
            nc.Origin = 'Web';
            nc.Subject = 'Routine Maintenance';
            nc.Type = 'Routine Maintenance';
            nc.Date_Reported__c = Date.today();
            nc.ProductId = caseRecord.ProductId;
            Integer daysToAdd = 0;
            if(requestToCycleMap.containsKey(caseRecord.Id))
            {
                daysToAdd = Integer.valueOf(requestToCycleMap.get(caseRecord.Id));
            }
            nc.Date_Due__c = Date.today().addDays(daysToAdd);
            maintenanceRequestInsert.add(nc);
        }
        insert maintenanceRequestInsert;
        
        
        
        //>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>Rewrite from here pleas<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        List <Equipment_Maintenance_Item__c> itemList = new List <Equipment_Maintenance_Item__c>();
        for(Case nc : maintenanceRequestInsert){
            for (Equipment_Maintenance_Item__c item : requestIdToEquipmentsMap.get(nc.ParentId))
            {
                Equipment_Maintenance_Item__c itemClone = item.clone();
                itemClone.Maintenance_Request__c = nc.Id;
                itemList.add(itemClone);
            }
        }
            
        insert itemList;   

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SFSE. Please read [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask) and [edit] your question to improve the chance you will get an answer. Posts that are just a code dump like this don't tend to get answered. You need to explain what your problem is clearly and identify more specifically where you face difficulty (include any errors, for example).

Comment: Looking at the code it seems to be trying to work in a bulkified manner. What is the reason you ask for rewrite help?

Comment: @PhilW I will try to ask better, thank you so much for the feedback. The reason I'm asking to rewrite this just for the learning purpose. I was thinking how can I rewrite this but I can't think of any solution.

Answer (score 4):

I see no reason why that nested loop needs to be re-written. A nested loop is, in fact, the correct way to handle iterating through child records.

The main problem that we can run into with nested loops is when you have something like

```java
// This approach is purposefully bad, and it should not be used
// If you see something similar to this, it should be re-written
for(Object1 obj1 :object1List){
    for(Object2 obj2 :object2List){
        if(obj1.Some_Field__c == obj2.Different_Field__c){
            // do work
        }
    }
}
```

Code like the above should be re-written, because it'll iterate N*M times (where N is the size of the first list, and M is the size of the second list). That's effectively O(N^2).

The current code that you're looking to rewrite will iterate N + M times, effectively O(N). It doesn't iterate over *all* child records in each iteration of the outer loop, just the child records related to a specific record.

#### +edit:

When you encounter a nested loop with `if(field1 == field2)` in it, the way to re-write that is to make use of a Map.

```java
// The key of the map doesn't need to be a string, though it'll usually be
//   that or an Id.
// The value of the map doesn't need to be a list, but if you're working 
//   with a nested loop it'll probably be a list.
Map<String, List<MySObject2>> targetValueToObjects = new Map<String, List<MySObject2>>();

// First, you loop over one of your objects to populate the map
for(MySObject2 obj2Record :obj2List){
    // This is an effective way to populate a map
    // Adding an initial value to the map when it doesn't yet contain
    //   our current "key" value means we don't need an ELSE or to
    //   do any extra null checks
    if(!targetValueToObjects.containsKey(obj2Record.Different_Field__c)){
        targetValueToObjects.put(obj2Record.Different_Field__c, new List<MySObject2>());
    }

    // Things like collections and custom Apex classes are stored in Maps
    //   as a "reference".
    // That means we can update the value stored by the map without needing
    //   to use .put() again
    // This approach doesn't work with maps where the value type is a primitive type
    //   (like Integer, Boolean, String, etc...)
    targetValueToObjects.get(obj2Record.Different_Field__c).add(obj2Record);
}

// Now we can execute the nested loop we're trying to fix
for(MySObject1 obj1Record :obj1List){
    // Since we took the time to make a map earlier, we can get rid of
    //   the if(field1 == field2) bit.
    // If there is nothing in the map for our target key, the inner loop
    //   doesn't execute
    // If there is something in the map, we'll only iterate over the
    //   matching records
    for(MySObject2 obj2Record :targetValueToObjects.get(obj1Record.Some_Field__c){
        // do work
    }
}
```

If you take a look at the code you currently have, you should start to see some parallels to this example approach.

- The `for(Case caseRecord :[query with a subquery])` loop adds a list of child records to a map
- The `for(Case nc : maintenanceRequestInsert)` loop feeds the inner loop with data from the map that was populated in the previous loop

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/282831/2984 

Comment: Hi @Derek F thank you so much for the response. I'm new to Apex and trying to learn. Can you please also give the solution to your example code like how can we rewrite it ?

Comment: @HoangBui I've edited my answer to include a generic "better version" to my generic "bad version".

Comment: @DerekF Thank you a lot for this. Helped me out a lot. Really appreciate this.