# ConcurrentPerOrgLongTxn Limit exceeded. Does SOQL query and Apex Callout timings gets counted

Tags: apex, governorlimits, concurrency

Apex CPU Time limit: Here Query timings and Callout timings does not get counted.

But would SOQL timings and Callout timings contribute to ConcurrentPerOrgLongTxn ?
We started hitting ConcurrentPerOrgLongTxn issue recently so wanted to check if optimizing SOQL will help here, so as to avoid **full table scans on table**?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the [Execution Governors and Limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm) documentation states:

> | Description | Limit |
> | --- | --- |
> | Number of synchronous concurrent transactions for long-running transactions that last longer than 5 seconds for each org.<sup>2</sup> | 10 |

...

> <sup>2</sup> If more transactions are started while the 10 long-running transactions are still running, they’re denied. HTTP callout processing time isn’t included when calculating this limit.

So, this only counts for *synchronous* transactions that take more than 5 seconds, not including callout time. While optimizing SOQL can sometimes help, a better strategy is to profile some of your code and figure out where the bottleneck is.

Potential solutions might include offloading intense code to asynchronous methods (future, Queueable, Batchable), finding methods that naturally take a long time because of poor programming practices (e.g. [nested for loops that should use a Map](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/282831/2984)), etc.

Unfortunately, we can't give you a for-certain, bulletproof solution to your problem. Every situation is unique. The governor limits already pretty heavily restrict how badly SOQL can perform (e.g. non-selective query errors, the 50,000 row query limit, etc), so optimizing SOQL is probably pretty low priority, unless there's something you know you can fix by adding indexes, or perhaps because you're dynamically generating SOQL, which should be avoided for large objects (string manipulation can eat up a lot of CPU time).

One suggestion, if your unit tests are up to date, is to run all of your tests and see which ones are taking the longest. Those may help you identify problem pieces of code. One trick I like to use is to set a [TraceFlag](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.232.0.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_traceflag.htm) that has all debug levels set to NONE, except for Profiling, which I set to FINEST.

This gives you a very small log that includes the total execution time of methods called, which can help pinpoint problems. Start by identifying the longest running tests, then try profiling them. If you still get stuck, you can also contact Technical Support. They can check logs to see what types of transactions are taking the most time.

Comment: Our org's standard objects, such as Account, task, Case, and some related objects are  all LDVs, where we have more than Millions of data, so I was going for optimizing SOQL to avoid full table scan. But running test classes seems good will try this. But test class wont query org data, so how will it pin point to root cause.

Comment: We recently faced an issue with a couple of selective and indexed SOQL queries because of what Salesforce called "prequery" scanning of a related record table (even though our use of said related object in the queries was simply to test for specific, non-null IDs) where the query and related objects are large volume. In the end Salesforce added some "skinny tables" in the production org to avoid the unnecessary prequery. The symptom was a timeout on the query itself, so not directly related here, but worth being aware of.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to replicate this exception in my org using
https://github.com/koenfaro90/SFDC-ConcurrentPerOrgLongTxn-Reproduction

I modified the code to hit the custom rest services which we have created in Apex.
I was able to exactly replicate the scenario where 10 concurrent clients are hitting the api, and as soon as 11th request came in it started throwing the exception. So we moved some heavy operations to Async.

The root cause was external system trying to hit our services concurrently more than the limit `10`. And the API was doing some CPU intensive work synchronously.

Comment: I will still accept `sfdcfox` answer, but just posted github link so that it will helpful in replicating this exception if there are custom rest services involved or to stress test your webservices.