# Can someone help me to convert the Apex class into a Batch Class

Tags: apex, developer

```
public class CLS_CodetabelleChange1 {
    
    public void splitupdate(List<Account> AccountListe){
          List<Account>updateListe=new List<Account>();
          List<Account>restListe=new List<Account>();
          if (!AccountListe.isEmpty()){
          for (Integer i = 0; i < AccountListe.size(); i++) {
                if (i < 49999) {
                    updateListe.add(AccountListe.get(i));
                }else{
                    restListe.add(AccountListe.get(i));
                }
              }
              update updateListe;
              splitupdate(restListe);
          }
    }
    
        public void splitupdate(List<Buchungskreis__c> BuchungskreisListe){
          List<Buchungskreis__c>updateListe=new List<Buchungskreis__c>();
          List<Buchungskreis__c>restListe=new List<Buchungskreis__c>();
          if (!BuchungskreisListe.isEmpty()){
          for (Integer i = 0; i < BuchungskreisListe.size(); i++) {
                if (i < 49999) {
                    updateListe.add(BuchungskreisListe.get(i));
                }else{
                    restListe.add(BuchungskreisListe.get(i));
                }
              }
              update updateListe;
              splitupdate(restListe);
          }
    }
    
    public void updatecode1(List<Codetabelle__c> newcode, List<Codetabelle__c> oldcode){
        List<Account>A1=new List<Account>();
        List<Account>A2=new List<Account>();
        List<Account>A3=new List<Account>();
        List<Account>A4=new List<Account>();
        List<Account>A5=new List<Account>();
        List<Account>A6=new List<Account>();
        List<Account>A7=new List<Account>();
        List<Account>A8=new List<Account>();
        List<Account>A9=new List<Account>();
        List<Account>A10=new List<Account>();
        List<Buchungskreis__c>B1=new List<Buchungskreis__c>();
        List<Buchungskreis__c>B2=new List<Buchungskreis__c>();
        
        for (Codetabelle__c c1: newcode){
            for (Codetabelle__c c2: oldcode){
                if (c1.id==c2.id){
                    if(c1.BuchungskreisFormel__c!=c2.BuchungskreisFormel__c)
                    {for (Account acc1:([Select id, BuKr__c from Account where BuKr__c =:c2.BuchungskreisFormel__c]))
                    {Account A11=new Account(id=acc1.id,BuKr__c =c1.BuchungskreisFormel__c);                     
                     A1.add(A11);}}
                    else 
                        if(c1.KontengruppenFormel__c!=c2.KontengruppenFormel__c)
                    {for (Account acc1:([Select id, Kontengr__c from Account where Kontengr__c =:c2.KontengruppenFormel__c]))
                    {Account A21=new Account(id=acc1.id,Kontengr__c =c1.KontengruppenFormel__c);                     
                     A2.add(A21);}}
                    else 
                        if(c1.KundengruppenFormel__c!=c2.KundengruppenFormel__c)
                    {for (Account acc1:([Select id, Kundengrp__c from Account where Kundengrp__c =:c2.KundengruppenFormel__c]))
                    {Account A31=new Account(id=acc1.id,Kundengrp__c =c1.KundengruppenFormel__c);                     
                     A3.add(A31);}}
                    else 
                        if(c1.KundenbezirkeFormel__c!=c2.KundenbezirkeFormel__c)
                    {for (Account acc1:([Select id, Kundenbezirk__c from Account where Kundenbezirk__c =:c2.KundenbezirkeFormel__c]))
                    {Account A41=new Account(id=acc1.id,Kundenbezirk__c =c1.KundenbezirkeFormel__c);                     
                     A4.add(A41);}}
                    else 
                        if(c1.VerkaeufergruppeDebitorFormel__c!=c2.VerkaeufergruppeDebitorFormel__c)
                    {for (Account acc1:([Select id, Verk_uferg__c from Account where Verk_uferg__c =:c2.VerkaeufergruppeDebitorFormel__c]))
                    {Account A51=new Account(id=acc1.id,Verk_uferg__c =c1.VerkaeufergruppeDebitorFormel__c);                     
                     A5.add(A51);}
                     
                     for (Buchungskreis__c Buch1:([Select id, Verk_ufergruppe__c from Buchungskreis__c where Verk_ufergruppe__c =:c2.VerkaeufergruppeDebitorFormel__c]))
                    {Buchungskreis__c B11=new Buchungskreis__c(id=Buch1.id,Verk_ufergruppe__c =c1.VerkaeufergruppeDebitorFormel__c);                     
                     B1.add(B11);}
                    
                    }
                    else 
                        if(c1.VerkaeuferbueroFormel__c!=c2.VerkaeuferbueroFormel__c)
                    {for (Account acc1:([Select id, Verk_Buero__c from Account where Verk_Buero__c =:c2.VerkaeuferbueroFormel__c]))
                    {Account A61=new Account(id=acc1.id,Verk_Buero__c =c1.VerkaeuferbueroFormel__c);                     
                     A6.add(A61);}
                     
                    for (Buchungskreis__c Buch1:([Select id, Verkaufsb_ro__c from Buchungskreis__c where Verkaufsb_ro__c =:c2.VerkaeuferbueroFormel__c]))
                    {Buchungskreis__c B21=new Buchungskreis__c(id=Buch1.id,Verkaufsb_ro__c =c1.VerkaeuferbueroFormel__c);                     
                     B2.add(B21);}}
                    else 
                        if(c1.Laender__c!=c2.Laender__c)
                    {for (Account acc1:([Select id, BillingCountry from Account where BillingCountry =:c2.Laender__c]))
                    {Account A71=new Account(id=acc1.id,BillingCountry =c1.Laender__c);                     
                     A7.add(A71);}}
                    else 
                        if(c1.BranchenschluesselFormel__c!=c2.BranchenschluesselFormel__c)
                    {for (Account acc1:([Select id, Branche_SAP__c from Account where Branche_SAP__c =:c2.BranchenschluesselFormel__c]))
                    {Account A81=new Account(id=acc1.id,Branche_SAP__c =c1.BranchenschluesselFormel__c);                     
                     A8.add(A81);}}
                    else 
                        if(c1.Verkaeufergruppe1Formel__c!=c2.Verkaeufergruppe1Formel__c)
                    {for (Account acc1:([Select id, Verkaeufergruppe1__c, Verkaeufergruppe2__c, LZLD_Gebiet__c,LZLD_Region__c, Regional_Leiter__c, LFB__c from Account where Verkaeufergruppe1__c =:c2.Verkaeufergruppe1Formel__c or Verkaeufergruppe2__c=:c2.Verkaeufergruppe1Formel__c or LZLD_Gebiet__c=:c2.Verkaeufergruppe1Formel__c or LZLD_Region__c=:c2.Verkaeufergruppe1Formel__c or Regional_Leiter__c=:c2.Verkaeufergruppe1Formel__c or LFB__c=:c2.Verkaeufergruppe1Formel__c]))
                    {Account A91=new Account(id=acc1.id);
                     if(acc1.Verkaeufergruppe1__c ==c2.Verkaeufergruppe1Formel__c){A91.Verkaeufergruppe1__c =c1.Verkaeufergruppe1Formel__c; }
                     if(acc1.Verkaeufergruppe2__c ==c2.Verkaeufergruppe1Formel__c){A91.Verkaeufergruppe2__c =c1.Verkaeufergruppe1Formel__c; }
                     if(acc1.LZLD_Gebiet__c ==c2.Verkaeufergruppe1Formel__c){A91.LZLD_Gebiet__c =c1.Verkaeufergruppe1Formel__c; }
                     if(acc1.LZLD_Region__c ==c2.Verkaeufergruppe1Formel__c){A91.LZLD_Region__c =c1.Verkaeufergruppe1Formel__c; }
                     if(acc1.Regional_Leiter__c ==c2.Verkaeufergruppe1Formel__c){A91.Regional_Leiter__c =c1.Verkaeufergruppe1Formel__c; }
                     if(acc1.LFB__c ==c2.Verkaeufergruppe1Formel__c){A91.LFB__c =c1.Verkaeufergruppe1Formel__c; }
                     A9.add(A91);}}
                    else
                        if(c1.Status_Profitcenter__c!=c2.Status_Profitcenter__c)
                    {for (Account acc1:([Select id, Status_Profitcenter__c from Account where Status_Profitcenter__c =:c2.Status_Profitcenter__c]))
                    {Account A111=new Account(id=acc1.id,Status_Profitcenter__c =c1.Status_Profitcenter__c);                     
                     A10.add(A111);}}
                    
                }
            }
        }
        splitupdate(A1);
        splitupdate(A2);
        splitupdate(A3);
        splitupdate(A4);
        splitupdate(A5);
        splitupdate(A6);
        splitupdate(A7);
        splitupdate(A8);
        splitupdate(A9);
        splitupdate(A10);
        splitupdate(B1);
        splitupdate(B2);
        
    }
    
    public void insertcode1(List<Codetabelle__c> newcode){
        List<Account>A1=new List<Account>();
        List<Account>A2=new List<Account>();
        List<Account>A3=new List<Account>();
        List<Account>A4=new List<Account>();
        List<Account>A5=new List<Account>();
        List<Account>A6=new List<Account>();
        List<Account>A7=new List<Account>();
        List<Account>A8=new List<Account>();
        List<Account>A9=new List<Account>();
        List<Account>A10=new List<Account>();
        List<Buchungskreis__c>B1=new List<Buchungskreis__c>();
        List<Buchungskreis__c>B2=new List<Buchungskreis__c>();
        
        for (Codetabelle__c c1: newcode){
            if(c1.BuchungskreisID__c!=null)
            {for (Account acc1:([Select id, BuKr__c from Account where BuKr__c =:c1.BuchungskreisID__c]))
            {Account A11=new Account(id=acc1.id,BuKr__c =c1.BuchungskreisFormel__c);                     
             A1.add(A11);}}
            else 
                if(c1.KontengruppenID__c!=null)
            {for (Account acc1:([Select id, Kontengr__c from Account where Kontengr__c =:c1.KontengruppenID__c]))
            {Account A21=new Account(id=acc1.id,Kontengr__c =c1.KontengruppenFormel__c);                     
             A2.add(A21);}}
            else 
                if(c1.KundengruppenID__c!=null)
            {for (Account acc1:([Select id, Kundengrp__c from Account where Kundengrp__c =:c1.KundengruppenID__c]))
            {Account A31=new Account(id=acc1.id,Kundengrp__c =c1.KundengruppenFormel__c);                     
             A3.add(A31);}}
            else 
                if(c1.KundenbezirkeID__c!=null)
            {for (Account acc1:([Select id, Kundenbezirk__c from Account where Kundenbezirk__c =:c1.KundenbezirkeID__c]))
            {Account A41=new Account(id=acc1.id,Kundenbezirk__c =c1.KundenbezirkeFormel__c);                     
             A4.add(A41);}}
            else 
                if(c1.VerkaeufergruppeDebitorID__c!=null)
            {for (Account acc1:([Select id, Verk_uferg__c from Account where Verk_uferg__c =:c1.VerkaeufergruppeDebitorID__c]))
            {Account A51=new Account(id=acc1.id,Verk_uferg__c =c1.VerkaeufergruppeDebitorFormel__c);                     
             A5.add(A51);}
             
            for (Buchungskreis__c Buch1:([Select id, Verk_ufergruppe__c from Buchungskreis__c where Verk_ufergruppe__c =:c1.VerkaeufergruppeDebitorID__c]))
            {Buchungskreis__c B11=new Buchungskreis__c(id=Buch1.id,Verk_ufergruppe__c =c1.VerkaeufergruppeDebitorFormel__c);                     
             B1.add(B11);}}
            else 
                if(c1.VerkaeuferbueroID__c!=null)
            {for (Account acc1:([Select id, Verk_Buero__c from Account where Verk_Buero__c =:c1.VerkaeuferbueroID__c]))
            {Account A61=new Account(id=acc1.id,Verk_Buero__c =c1.VerkaeuferbueroFormel__c);                     
             A6.add(A61);}
            
            for (Buchungskreis__c Buch1:([Select id, Verkaufsb_ro__c from Buchungskreis__c where Verkaufsb_ro__c =:c1.VerkaeuferbueroID__c]))
            {Buchungskreis__c B21=new Buchungskreis__c(id=Buch1.id,Verkaufsb_ro__c =c1.VerkaeuferbueroFormel__c);                     
             B2.add(B21);}}
            else 
                if(c1.Laendercode__c!=null)
            {for (Account acc1:([Select id, BillingCountry from Account where BillingCountry =:c1.Laendercode__c]))
            {Account A71=new Account(id=acc1.id,BillingCountry =c1.Laender__c);                     
             A7.add(A71);}}
            else 
                if(c1.BranchenschluesselID__c!=null)
            {for (Account acc1:([Select id, Branche_SAP__c from Account where Branche_SAP__c =:c1.BranchenschluesselID__c]))
            {Account A81=new Account(id=acc1.id,Branche_SAP__c =c1.BranchenschluesselFormel__c);                     
             A8.add(A81);}}
            else 
                if(c1.Verkaeufergruppe1ID__c!=null)
            {for (Account acc1:([Select id, Verkaeufergruppe1__c, Verkaeufergruppe2__c, LZLD_Gebiet__c,LZLD_Region__c, Regional_Leiter__c, LFB__c from Account where Verkaeufergruppe1__c =:c1.Verkaeufergruppe1ID__c or Verkaeufergruppe2__c=:c1.Verkaeufergruppe1ID__c or LZLD_Gebiet__c=:c1.Verkaeufergruppe1ID__c or LZLD_Region__c=:c1.Verkaeufergruppe1ID__c or Regional_Leiter__c=:c1.Verkaeufergruppe1ID__c or LFB__c=:c1.Verkaeufergruppe1ID__c]))
            {Account A91=new Account(id=acc1.id);
             if(acc1.Verkaeufergruppe1__c ==c1.Verkaeufergruppe1ID__c){acc1.Verkaeufergruppe1__c =c1.Verkaeufergruppe1Formel__c; }
             if(acc1.Verkaeufergruppe2__c ==c1.Verkaeufergruppe1ID__c){acc1.Verkaeufergruppe2__c =c1.Verkaeufergruppe1Formel__c; }
             if(acc1.LZLD_Gebiet__c ==c1.Verkaeufergruppe1ID__c){acc1.LZLD_Gebiet__c =c1.Verkaeufergruppe1Formel__c; }
             if(acc1.LZLD_Region__c ==c1.Verkaeufergruppe1ID__c){acc1.LZLD_Region__c =c1.Verkaeufergruppe1Formel__c; }
             if(acc1.Regional_Leiter__c ==c1.Verkaeufergruppe1ID__c){acc1.Regional_Leiter__c =c1.Verkaeufergruppe1Formel__c; }
             if(acc1.LFB__c ==c1.Verkaeufergruppe1ID__c){acc1.LFB__c =c1.Verkaeufergruppe1Formel__c; }
             A9.add(A91);}}
            else
                if(c1.Status_Profitcenter_ID__c!=null)
            {for (Account acc1:([Select id, Status_Profitcenter__c from Account where Status_Profitcenter__c =:c1.Status_Profitcenter_ID__c]))
            {Account A111=new Account(id=acc1.id,Status_Profitcenter__c =c1.Status_Profitcenter__c);                     
             A10.add(A111);}}      
        }
        
        splitupdate(A1);
        splitupdate(A2);
        splitupdate(A3);
        splitupdate(A4);
        splitupdate(A5);
        splitupdate(A6);
        splitupdate(A7);
        splitupdate(A8);
        splitupdate(A9);
        splitupdate(A10);
        splitupdate(B1);
        splitupdate(B2);
        
    }
  
}
```

Comment: What's the specific problem/challenge? At the moment this reads as asking us to do it for you.

Comment: yes i need help to convert this class into the batch class, i m confused how to start the batch class

Comment: @Girbot This is an [X-Y Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). I'll add an answer, but this is going to take a minute.

Comment: @sfdcfox, i have followed your advice and amended the code please have a look because i m getting the duplicate variable issues.

Answer (score 2):

Changing this code to batchable won't fix things. The problem here is that this code will inherently cause CPU timeouts and/or SOQL limit exceptions, even in batchable context.

First, to avoid the CPU timeout problem on large lists, you need to not run a loop inside a loop. This causes exponential growth of CPU time. To fix it, we use a Map. Note that [nested for loops are acceptable in some cases](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/282831/2984), just not this specific case.

```
// Bad
for (Codetabelle__c c1 : newcode) {
  for (Codetabelle__c c2 : oldcode) {
    if (c1.id == c2.id) {
      // Rest of code ...
```

...

```
// Good
Map<Id, Codetabelle__c> alte_Codetabellenkarte = new Map<Id, Codetabelle__c>(
  oldcode
);
for(Codetabelle__c neue_Codetabelle: newCode) {
  Codetabelle__c alte_Codetabelle = alte_Codetabellenkarte.get(neue_Codetabelle.Id);
    // Rest of code ...
```

Second, you can't repeatedly query inside a loop, so you must aggregate all of your queries for efficiency.

```
Map<Id, Id> BuchungskreisFormelkarte = new Map<Id, Id>();
Map<Id, Id> KontengruppenFormelkarte = new Map<Id, Id>();
// Create maps for each code mapping.

for (Codetabelle__c neue_Codetabelle : newCode) {
  Codetabelle__c alte_Codetabelle = alte_Codetabellenkarte.get(
    neue_Codetabelle.Id
  );
  if (
    neue_Codetabelle.BuchungskreisFormel__c !=
    alte_Codetabelle.BuchungskreisFormel__c
  ) {
    BuchungskreisFormelkarte.put(
      alte_Codetabelle.BuchungskreisFormel__c,
      neue_Codetabelle.BuchungskreisFormel__c
    );
  }
  if (
    neue_Codetabelle.KontengruppenFormel__c !=
    alte_Codetabelle.KontengruppenFormel__c
  ) {
    KontengruppenFormelkarte.put(
      alte_Codetabelle.KontengruppenFormel__c,
      neue_Codetabelle.KontengruppenFormel__c
    );
  }
  // Repeat for the rest of the conditions...
}
Map<Id, Account> aktualisierenkarte = new Map<Id, Account>();
for (Account Konto : [
  SELECT BuKr__c, Kontengr__c // Include all the fields you need here
  FROM Account
  WHERE
    BuKr__c IN :BuchungskreisFormelkarte.keySet()
    OR Kontengr__c = :kontengruppenformelkarte.keySet()
  // add more OR filters for each field we check
]) {
  Account aktualisieren = new Account(Id = Konto.Id);
  Id buchungskreisformel = buchungskreisformelkarte.get(Konto.BuKr__c);
  if (buchungskreisformel != null) {
    aktualisieren.BuKr__c = buchungskreisformel;
    aktualisierenkarte.put(Konto.Id, aktualisieren);
  }
  Id kontengruppenformel = kontengruppenformelkarte.get(Kono.Kontengr__c);
  if (kontengruppenformel != null) {
    aktualisieren.Kontengr__c = kontengruppenformel;
    aktualisierenkarte.put(Konto.Id, aktualisieren);
  }
  // Repeat for the rest of the conditions...
}

update aktualisierenkarte.values();
```

I apologize for my German, as I don't actually speak it, I'm just decent with Google translate.

In English, we create a map for each of the old value to the new value by comparing the old code mapping to the new code mapping. Next, we query all accounts that match any of the old code mapping values (`.keyset()`), and if we find a mapping to a new value, we add this to the map of accounts to update (`aktualisierenkarte`).

Doing this reduces the queries we need to use to just 1, and just one DML statement. This is presumably done in a trigger, so we will never have more than 200 records to process at once.

In summary, there is no need for a batchable, just heavy optimization.